# Mandrill not showing the right Cc information

Tags: php, mandrill

This issue really driving me crazy this past hours. Why is the email that send with Mandrill not showing the right information about the Cc email address.

So for example, I want to send email to

- receiver_to_a@mail.com
- receiver_cc_a@mail.com
- receiver_cc_b@mail.com

When I see the email header on receiver_cc_a@mail.com. its always show no cc, and that email is send "to" receiver_cc_a@mail.com, not as cc

Is anyone having the same problem? I already try sending email in PHP with PhpMailer and also try from the PHP API from Mandrill itself but no luck.

Comment: Show your code, and also what API library you are using to talk to Mandrill

Comment: I get this using official library v1.0.55

Comment: Turn out, there is a setting in mandrill.. i forget where, but there is a setting to non active this problem

Comment: I think you mean: Mandrill - Settings -  Sending Defaults - Expose The List Of Recipients When Sending To Multiple Addresses

Comment: @Riscie yes, that is the setting

Answer (score 14):

You need to set the option `preserve_recipients` to `true`.

```
$message = array(
    'html' => '<p>Example HTML content</p>',
    'text' => 'Example text content',
    'subject' => 'example subject',
    'from_email' => 'message.from_email@example.com',
    'from_name' => 'Example Name',
    'to' => array(
        array(
            'email' => 'recipient.email@example.com',
            'name' => 'Recipient Name',
            'type' => 'to'
        ),
        array(
            'email' => 'ccrecipient.email@example.com',
            'name' => 'Recipient Name',
            'type' => 'cc'
        )
    ),
    'headers' => array('Reply-To' => 'message.reply@example.com'),
    'preserve_recipients' => true
);
```

Comment: I don't know why people didn't upvote your answer. It's really helpful. :)