# Laravel Mail Not Correcting CC'ing Emails

Tags: php, laravel, email

I am trying to get a Laravel Mail setup to correctly send emails with CC'd recipients.

```
     $email_addresses = ['test1@example.com','test2@example.com','test3@example.com']
     $to_email = array_shift($email_addresses);
     Mail::mailer('mandrill')
           ->to([$to_email])
           ->cc($email_addresses)
           ->send(new PortalEmail($message));
```

But it is sending an email to every address in the list of CC'd emails, with no CC'd recipients. Instead sends all of the CC'd address recipients a copy of the email, with the email address as the `to` email address.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42691122/mandrill-not-showing-the-right-cc-information might be of some help, though it's not Laravel specific.

Answer (score 1):

This is a feature of Mandrill. You can either change this setting globally in your account, or you can pass in a custom header to enforce the setting per message.

##### Global account setting

The documentation for changing the setting globally is at https://mailchimp.com/developer/transactional/docs/outbound-email/#multiple-recipients.

From the docs:

> To control whether recipients can see each others’ information in the `To` header of your messages, navigate to the `Sending Defaults` page and select or unselect `Expose The List Of Recipients When Sending To Multiple Addresses`. You can override these global settings on a per-message basis with the `preserve_recipients` parameter in your API calls, or with the `X-MC-PreserveRecipients` SMTP header.

##### Per-message override

To override this global setting on a per-message basis, you can send your email with the custom `X-MC-PreserveRecipients` header.

To do this, add a `headers()` function to your `PortalEmail` mailable:

```
use Illuminate\Mail\Mailables\Headers;
 
public function headers(): Headers
{
    return new Headers(
        text: [
            'X-MC-PreserveRecipients' => 'true',
        ],
    );
}
```

This will turn on the `preserve_recipients` setting so that Mandrill will not modify the `To`/`Cc` headers.

---

Documentation for the customer header is at https://mailchimp.com/developer/transactional/docs/smtp-integration/#x-mc-preserverecipients.

From the docs:

> If you send to more than one recipient at a time and want all recipients to see each other’s information, set this option to `true`. If it’s set to `false`, Mailchimp will rewrite the `To` and `Cc` headers to only show information about an individual recipient.

---

Documentation on Laravel mail headers is at https://laravel.com/docs/10.x/mail#headers.

Answer (score -2):

You are correctly setting the to recipient to the first email address in the list using ->to($to_email). Then, you can pass the remaining email addresses to the cc method using ->cc($email_addresses).

```
$email_addresses = ['test1@example.com', 'test2@example.com', 'test3@example.com'];

$to_email = array_shift($email_addresses);

Mail::mailer('mandrill')
    ->to($to_email)
    ->cc($email_addresses)
    ->send(new PortalEmail($message));
```

Comment: That is exactly what I am doing, but still no CC'd emails.